# Jenkins: How to build multiple projects/app sequentially via individual defined Jenkins items

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play

I have multiple apps in Google Play using the same code base.
For each of these apps I have created Items in Jenkins that perform building and signing the apk and uploading them to the Play Store.

Say I have 10 of those apps. I don't want to manually go to each items and start the build procedure.

What I would like is to create a seperate item in Jenkins where I define which (and in which order) of the items in Jenkins i want to start.

Is this possible and how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is: MultiJob Plugin , you can create multiples job for each of the functionality and wrap all of those in a single multijob.
you can then divide the MultiJob into Multi phases where you can set the parameters like
- to proceed to next job only if current job success or completed.
- to run the jobs in multiphase sequentially or parallel and lot other things.

Answer (score 0):

The [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution would be to just create a job that triggers your 10 jobs via the [build](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step) step, see the optional *wait* argument for making it serial and *propagate* to get a combined status.